# Multipipe function breaking stdin in c?

Tags: c, unix

Some friends and I are trying to implement a complete shell, and I'm in charge of the multipipe function.

The problem is that just after the function ends and return, the `read()` in the main loop seems to endlessly read 0 bytes and cause an infinite loop. However, the function outputs the intended result.

After spending around a week trying to debug my function we came to the following conclusion: somehow, I broke `STDIN`.

What could possibly cause this?

Here is the full function minus error checking for clarity purpose.

```
int do_pipe( t_parser *paser, int fd, t_info *info, int j )
{
    int    status;
    pid_t  pid;
    int    pipefd[ 2 ];

    if ( j == 0 )
    {
        while ( parser->next != NULL )
            parser = parser->next;

        fd = 1;
    }

    if ( parser->prev )
        pipe( pipefd );

    pid = fork();

    if ( pid == 0 )
    {
        if ( parser->prev )
        {
            close( pipefd[1] );
            dup2( pipefd[0], 0 );
            close( pipefd[0] );
        }

        if ( parser->next )
        {
            if ( parser->prev )
                close( pipefd[0] );

            dup2( fd, 1 );
            close( fd );
        }

        my_execve( parser, info->env );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( parser->prev )
            close( pipefd[0] );

        if ( fd != 1 )
            close( fd );

        j++;

        if ( parser->prev )
            do_pipe( parser->prev, pipefd[1], info, j );
            waitpid( pid, &status, 0 );
    }

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: stdin isn't one thing.. it is different depending on what you are talking about, so you broke your processes file pointer to your specific stdin?

Comment: Does the caller set `fd == 0`?  If so, `if( fd != 1 ) close( fd )` will close stdin.

Comment: BTW, using `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` is a good idea.

Comment: If `read` returns 0, you have hit an eof. Whatever your function does, it cannot change that.

Comment: Is this *really* the code verbatim? I ask because the function has a parameter named `paser` (no "r"), but the code in the function body uses a variable named `parser`.

Comment: No, it's not. I forgot the r, as you mentioned.

Comment: Please read up on what an SSCCE  ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) is, as it makes life much easier.  Note that it does require the failing code (verbatim--no typos), but it doesn't require your whole parsing code - it would be sufficient to manufacture a `t_parser` structure containing the relevant information to reproduce the problem.